# Custom weekly axis labels by facet in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some daily data that I want to show in different facets by day of the week. I don't like my x axis labels here, which are all aligned the same, in this case lining up with the Thursday facet. Is there a way to get different axis breaks by facet, which line up to that facet's data?

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(dt = seq.Date(as.Date("2023-11-01"), as.Date("2023-11-25"), "day"),
           val = sin(1:25)) |>
  mutate(dow = lubridate::wday(dt, label = TRUE)) |>
  ggplot(aes(dt, val)) +
  geom_col(width = 6) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "7 days", date_labels = "%b\n%d", minor_breaks = NULL) +
  facet_wrap(~dow, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` to set the breaks individually per facet. Personally I would also combine with `facet_grid` to make use of `space="free_x"` and to have bars of equal width:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  dt = seq(
    as.Date("2023-11-01"),
    as.Date("2023-11-25"), "day"
  ),
  val = sin(1:25)
) |>
  mutate(dow = lubridate::wday(dt, label = TRUE))

ggplot(dat, aes(dt, val)) +
  geom_col(width = 6) +
  facet_grid(~dow, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    x = lapply(split(dat, ~dow), \(x) {
      scale_x_continuous(
        breaks = unique(x$dt),
        labels = ~ format(.x, "%b\n%d"),
        minor_breaks = NULL
      )
    })
  )
```

[image]